# Choosing the right sampling frequency for WLAN 802.11ac signal (BW : 80 MHz)?

Tags: signal, sampling

I’ve got a WLAN 802.11ac signal & it’s bandwidth is 80MHz, now I would like to know the ideal sampling frequency for this signal.

As per the nyquist theorem , the sampling frequency could be 160 MHz and above, is it correct?

Comment: Practically, 160MHz isn't enough. Suggest 200MHz or higher.

Comment: It depends how you want to deal with it.  You do indeed need something like 160-200 MSPS worth of *data* to represent that.  But often the preferred format for arithmetic modulation/demodulation etc is paired I and Q samples - for that, you'd have 80-100 MSPS worth of I and another 80-100 MSPS worth of Q, and your bandwidth would extend from - 40 MHz through 0 to +40 MHz.  Numerical operations can convert between the two types of format - so for example, you might use one fast ADC and generate IQ in the digital realm, or you might use a slower dual ADC.

Answer (score 1):

You want a multiple of the OFDM channel distance (for easier decoding) that is greater than the Nyquist frequency plus overhead required for the transition bands of preselection filters.

I'd probably use 240 MHz and an analog preselection filter with a passband width of 90-100 MHz.